# Deserializing interfaces with Rest controller in Java Spring framework

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have inherited a simple enough *controller*. The problem is that it returns **interface** and Spring AFAIK cannot **deserialize** if it can't *instantiate*. I can fix it with one annotation on (each) transport interface, but it removes any benefit of returning an interface as opposed to a concrete class and steps out of bounds of DTO responsibilities.

Therefore my question is can something be done on the **client** side to consume controller as it is? If not, can something be done on **controller** code without altering `UserDto` interface?

Here's the Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {
    // ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserDto create(@RequestBody UserDto user) throws ServiceException {
        return  service.save(user);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Here's the test that acts as a client and consumes the controller:

```
    @Test
    public void UserControllerRealTest() {
        ClientUser user1 = new ClientUserImpl("ADSMarko", "Marko Savić", "Slayer!!!");
        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<ClientUser> request = new HttpEntity<>(user1);
        UserDto result1 = rt.postForObject(createUrl, request, UserDtoImpl.class);
        System.out.println("User " + result1.getUsername() + " saved with id " + result1.getId());

        ClientUser user2 = new ClientUserImpl("Marko", "Marko Savić", "Slayer!!!");
        request = new HttpEntity<>(user2);
        ParameterizedTypeReference<UserDto> ptr = new ParameterizedTypeReference<UserDto>() {};
        ResponseEntity<UserDto> re = rt.exchange(createUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, ptr);
        UserDto result2 = re.getBody();
        System.out.println("User " + result2.getUsername() + " saved with id " + result2.getId());
    }
```

Bellow is the interface in question. It works with the leading annotation, but without it throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = UserDtoImpl.class) // Or the longer annotation
public interface UserDto {
    // ... just getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Is your question really: how to make it work without the need to add the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation to the `UserDto` interface? The error message gives a suggestion: have a custom deserializer.

Comment: You need to custom de-serialize, and the deserializer needs to be able to deal with the sub classes of the interface.

Comment: As I said above, my question is can something be done on the *client* side to consume controller as it is? If not, can something be done on *controller* code without altering ```UserDto``` interface? Yes, without putting ```@JsonDeserialize``` annotation. IMO it is not transport interface's responsibility to hold information how to deserialize. It's responsibility is to transport data to and from back end as far as possible. When it's no longer possible, another layer and mapper should be added.